# how to get real link from wordpress api

Tags: url, wordpress, wordpress-theming, hyperlink

im using wordpress permalink "post name" %postname%/

so my page link looks like this :

```
http://designonsky.com/sample-page/
```

[image: post name permalink]

but i want to get the real link :

```
http://designonsky.com/?page_id=2
```

[image: real link]

im asking if there's a wordpress function ( or php function ) to do that .

no .htaccess please .

sorry for my english

thanks advanced!

Comment: Change your permalink settings to default

Comment: im building a wordpress menu , so im asking for a function !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, you could use something like:

```
if( is_page() ){
  echo home_url() . '/?pageid=' . get_the_ID();
}
elseif( is_single() ){
  echo home_url() . '/?p=' . get_the_ID();
}
elseif ( is_category() ){
  echo home_url() . '/?cat=' . get_the_ID();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_the_ID](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) method to return the current page or post id.

Comment: how to detect if this link , is for post , page or category ?

thats the problem with get_the_id